# Count total amount of completed CSS animations

Tags: javascript, php, css

On my webpage i have a small simple wheel-like icon in the top navigation bar which rotates 360 degree on hover and back when the mouse is removed via this CSS code:

```
.img-wheel{
border-radius: 50%;
border:5px solid <?php echo $nav_text_color; ?>;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;
}
.img-wheel:hover {
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
```

I want a counter next to it which shows how many times someone completed the whole animation (or, if easier, just how many times someone hovered over the wheel).
Preferable it is an absolute total, so user 1 hovered once and the counter adds +1, than user 2 opens the site with the counter already on 1, user 2 hovers once and it will show a 2. User 1 comes back to the site and sees the counter on 2.

Since the wheel is in the navigation bar the counter also shouldn't reset when another page is opened.

I know this will require server side scripting and i am curious where to start.
My idea was to add a simple counter.txt file with only a 0 to start with. And some script should edit the file by adding +1 every time the animation is completed. But that would also require to reload counter.txt every time it is edited, otherwise it wouldn't be seen live by the user.

Do you guys have any brilliant idea's?

Comment: You need: a database, and jQuery. You'll have to use jQuery to 'listen' to the hover event. If it gets hovered, jQuery calls a function that then calls a PHP page (all in the background). That PHP page does a check if the requested IP (or username, if applicable. Whatever, really) is already in the database, and if not, it increments the counter (which then would also be in the database).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have an element on the page which changes for all users when a user interacts with it.

I would suggest you build a js function which changes the class of the wheel element to change the animation, and have it ajax post back against the server in the same hit. The next issue will be storing the data, so you will probably need some sort of shared data store, like a database or key-value server where you're going to need to store an identifier (of some sort) and call the count of those rows the counter.  I advise against a file, as this  you're likely to get race conditions on a single text file.

Comment: Even if you weren't running (pun intended) into race conditions, you'd still have the issue of not having the same visitor count twice. You could of course have another file, with an IP address on every rule. Get the file contents in PHP, explode on new rule, check if current IP is in that array, etc etc. A database with Javascript is, in my opinion, the best way.

Comment: The site is aimed only on a small local audience (kids). I want this counter so they can commonly 'work' on the same thing when they're at home and set some achievements on certain numbers (maybe change the color of the site at x hovers, something like that). This also means that one user should be able to add to the counter multiple times in the same session. My hosting service includes 5 MySQL databases and Php, CGI, XML, Perl support (I’m only familiar with php) and my site includes jQuery.

Comment: Yes, as I was saying, you could store an Identifier (IP or DB-ID ect) for each run in, and the number of times an individual user has seen it would be the count of the number of rows in the database for that IP address, or other identifier.  If you wanted it to be resettable, you could generate an ID and send it as a cookie / Session for the ID, and re-add using said ID from inspecting the cookie /Session when the server encounters it.